# Intel NUC won't boot from SSD automatically but boots when selected manually

Tags: boot, ssd, intel-nuc

Just installed Ubuntu Server 19.04 on my NUC and running into "A boot device has not been detected" issue.

Note that if I press F10 and select the same SSD as the boot device, the NUC boots up, loads and runs Ubuntu just fine.  It's just that this doesn't happen automatically.

I have only 1 SSD installed; no other SSDs or HDDs or USB drives.

Device: NUC6i5

BIOS Settings

```
 - BIOS Version: SYSKLI35.86A.0071.* (upgraded after running into this issue with SYSKLI35.86A.0065.*)
 - Boot Order / UEFI / UEFI Boot: Disabled (unchecked)
 - Boot Order / Legacy / Legacy Boot: Enabled (checked)
 - Boot Order / Legacy / Boot Drive Order: SATA Port 2 Samsung SSD
 - Boot Priority / UEFI Boot Priority / UEFI Boot: Disabled (unchecked)
 - Boot Configuration / UEFI Boot / <All Options, except Boot Network Devices Last> : Disabled (unchecked)
 - Boot Configuration / Boot Devices / Internal UEFI Shell: Disabled (unchecked)
 - Boot Configuration / Boot Devices / USB: Enabled (checked)
 - Boot Configuration / Boot Devices / Optical: Enabled (checked)
 - Boot Configuration / Boot Devices / Network Boot: Disabled (unchecked)
 - Secure Boot / Config / Secure Boot: Disabled (unchecked)
```

I re-installed Ubuntu and manually made the SSD as the Boot Device during installation but still same results.
Upgraded to latest BIOS version and still no luck.

Please help.

Comment: It looks like you want to use Legacy boot for Ubuntu. Is UEFI set to that mode?

Comment: I have a similar NUC but I don't see the same choices you have in the UEFI setup. I have everything (both UEFI and Legacy) enabled (checked). But I am have installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode, not Legacy. In any case, try enabling UEFI boot modes in BIOS and see if that changes anything.

Comment: hi @user68186, yes, I have stayed away from UEFI due to all the issues people ran into early on.
I would like to wait and see if there are other options/suggestions/solutions.  Don't really want to try out Ubuntu installation in UEFI mode, but may have to do it if no viable alternatives surface.

Comment: I was suggesting enabling the UEFI boot options in the BIOS (UEFI) rather than reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode. If you decide to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. I didn't have any issues with my NUC6i5. I have only one OS, Ubuntu and "secure boot" is off in UEFI. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: thanks for the clarification @user68186, the problem seems to be resolved now.  all I had to do was check and then uncheck the UEFI Boot setting - without ever saving the change.
So, in reality I didn't change any configuration, but somehow it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as answer to have a clear answer on this question.

The solution, in my case, was to check and then uncheck the UEFI Boot option.

```
Boot Order / UEFI / UEFI Boot: Disabled (unchecked)
```

Please note that I didn't really change any setting but somehow it worked.

If that did not work then I was going to actually enable the UEFI Boot option, as suggested by @user68186

Something that I should've mentioned in my original post is that I had Ubuntu 19.04 Desktop running on the system just fine before I tried to install Ubuntu Server 19.04 - with same boot config: Legacy Boot and UEFI Boot disabled.